# Using HTML within a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm working on an FAQ type project using AngularJS. I have a number of questions and answers I need to import into the page and thought it would be a good idea to use a service/directive to load the content in dynamically from JSON.

The text strings are quite unwieldily (639+ characters) and the overall hesitation I have is adding HTML into the JSON object to format the text (Line breaks etc).

Is pulling HTML from JSON considered bad practice practice, and is there a better way to solve this? I'd prefer to avoid using multiple templates but it's starting to seem like a better approach.

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to make a page that doesn't do a full load to do a new question this sounds fine.  I wonder why wrap the JSON object around the html instead of just using a normal get request?

Comment: Mostly because the strings are around 3-4 paragraphs long so they need some sort of line break. Really the only thing I want to use will be <p> tags. Thanks for the answer, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using AngularJS and already have a build step, [html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-html2js) could help you with turning HTML templates into JS, which can then be concat'd and minified.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing the incoming JSON before sending it to the page and just adding in a `<br />` everywhere you run into a `\n`. That way the JSON is more universally usable if you ever decide you want to port the data to another medium.